# Video background not full on mobile version

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, responsive-design

I have a video background on my landing page which looks like this:

**Landing Page**

[image: Landing Page]

But when I try to view the mobile version of the site it looks like this:

**Landing Page - Mobile Version**

[image: Landing Page - Mobile Version]

(Don't mind the sponsor button, it's supposed to be there.)

I also have this line for responsiveness and set the width of the background to 100%.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Am I lacking anything?

Here's the code:

```html
<section class="header6 cid-qshCkd3Et8 mbr-fullscreen" data-bg-video="" id="header6-1i" data-rv-view="970" style="background: rgba(169, 198, 222, 1) none repeat scroll 0px 0px;">
    <div class="mbr-overlay" style="width: 100%;">
     <video playsinline="playsinline" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
     <source src="vid/skybg4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </div><!-- rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) -->
```

Comment: Were those screenshots taken at the same time on the video? Just want to make sure we're comparing apples to apples. Also, looks like you are missing the closing `</video>` tag, which may be part of the issue on the mobile browser.

Comment: @RenzoMiranda what is the exact problem? the background is a different size.. as with all mobile backgrounds.. do you want to retain the black border? The sponsor button is probably what is interfering with the dots underneath the text? (btw you're missing a closing </section> tag in your snippet)

Answer (score 0):

On a mobile device in portrait mode, width is smaller than height. 
Your videos width is set to 100%. 
You could give the section a height of 100vh and then vertically center the video.